# setting Language of tableau server does not work

Tags: tableau-api

I set Language of tableau server and

```
tsm restart
```

and then I got

```
Stopping service...
Job id is '8', timeout is 60 minutes.
Service stopped successfully.
Starting service...
```

[image]

However, language is still English

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this post: https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/lang_intro.htm

It says language is derived by a number of factors. Could be your change is overridden by preferences elsewhere